# Creating nested scenes in Samsung Smart TV Apps

Tags: samsung-smart-tv, smart-tv

I am a rookie and I have a silly question. How can created nested scenes?
I have read the '[scene manager](http://www.samsungdforum.com/Guide/art00088/index.html)' article but I can not find the Scene Manager to create three scenes nested inside each other
I want to have two resized subscenes within the main scene but I don't know how I can connect them.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Scenes are only divs, which position is set to absolute. Main Scene have to set width to 960px (1280px) and height to 540px (720px) through CSS stylesheets. Other Scenes size can be same or smaller.

`$.sfScene.show('SceneID')` set scene property display to block
`$.sfScene.hide('SceneID')` set scene property display to none

`$.sfScene.get('SceneID')` makes an instance of Scene, in other words instance of Scene object
exactly instance of `function SceneSceneID()`